# Why I use SmallWidth doesn't work for supporting 1080x2244 pixels device?

Tags: android

My device is Huawei Meta20 (6.53 inches, 1080x2244 pixels and DensityDpi is 420), for supporting its UI I create a values-sw420dp resources, but it's strange that when my application was running on Huawei Meta20, the UI layout only read from values-sw360dp, not values-sw420dp as well as values-sw411dp, values-sw480dp etc. Could you tell me where is my problem when use Small-Width if you know? Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fetching the device's width programmatically:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();    
float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```

I think you'll find that it's not really 420dp.

Comment: You are right, dpWidth is 360dp, I misunderstood the smallwidth rules. Thanks.